# Python 2.7 - Continued Fraction Expansion - Understanding the error

Tags: python, division, fractions, integer-division, continued-fractions

I've written this code to calculate the continued fraction expansion of a rational number N using the Euclidean algorithm:

```
from __future__ import division

def contFract(N):
    while True:
        yield N//1
        f = N - (N//1)
        if f == 0:
            break
        N = 1/f
```

If say N is 3.245 the function is never ending as apparently f never equals 0. The first 10 terms of the expansion are:

> [3.0, 4.0, 12.0, 3.0, 1.0, 247777268231.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0]

Which is clearly an error since the actual expansion is only:

> [3;4,12,3,1] or [3;4,12,4]

What's causing the problem here? Is it some sort of rounding error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you're testing `f == 0` (integer 0) which is almost never true for floats. So the loop goes on forever.

Instead, check for some precision of equivalent to 0 ([which can be wrong sometimes](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>>
>>> def contFract(N):
...     while True:
...         yield N//1
...         f = N - (N//1)
...         if f < 0.0001:  # or whatever precision you consider close enough to 0
...             break
...         N = 1/f
...
>>>
>>> list(contFract(3.245))
[3.0, 4.0, 12.0, 3.0, 1.0]
>>>
```

And in case `f` can be negative, do either `-0.0001 < f < 0.0001` or `abs(f) < 0.0001`. Which is also considered inaccurate, see the linked article.

And wrt my comment to use `int(N)` instead of `N//1` because it's clearer - it is *slightly* less efficient:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('N = 2.245; N//1', number=10000000)
1.5497028078715456
>>> timeit.timeit('N = 2.245; int(N)', number=10000000)
1.7633858824068103
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're staying, `N//1` is not equivalent to `N` i.e. 3.223//1 = 3.

Comment: Again I don't see your point, if I use `int(N)` instead of `N//1` I receive the same error. With `N = 1/f` I am trying to get the reciprocal of f, not use floor division. If I print 1/f for the first 10 expansions I get:              `4.08163265306
12.25
4.0
1.0
2.47777268231e+11
4.73320814676
1.36386918834
2.74824038982
1.33646888567
2.97204301075`

Comment: Ah, ok I see your point now, had't yet seen your changes to your post

Comment: I meant use `int(N)` instead of `N//1` only because it's clearer. Python will do float math when required. Although, appears less performant (will add that code).

Comment: Testing for precision seems a bit messy, I thought there might be a neater way to do this, but thanks

Comment: The joy of floats :-) And if this answers your question, feel free to Accept.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `float` for your operation, unfortunately some of the numbers can't be represented as a number in binary representation.

there are two options how to fix it, first - assume that your numbers are "close enough" (even new Python 3.5.2 introduces `math.isclose`), or you are using different implementation of floats e.g. `Decimal` you can get proper results.

N.b. this is why for all financial systems, nobody is ever using floats, only int/bigint or Decimals.

```
 In [21] > N = decimal.Decimal('3.245')

 In [22] > while True:
    print 'N: %s' % (N//1,)
    f = N - N//1
    print 'f: %s' % f
    if f == 0:
        break
    N = 1/f

N: 3
f: 0.245
N: 4
f: 0.081632653061224489795918367
N: 12
f: 0.25000000000000000000000005
N: 3
f: 0.999999999999999999999999200
N: 1
f: 8.00E-25
N: 1250000000000000000000000
f: 0
```

Comment: Good suggestion to use `math.isclose` but, as you pointed out, it's Python 3.x and the OP is using the future division, so he/she is on Py2k.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently the bug is due to the integer division of 4.0 by 1. 4.0 in floating point representation has a error involved (if you have idea about floating point representation). So actually int(4.0) < 4. This causes the N//1 to become 3.0 and the fraction f is something like 0.999999.... So this never ends. Print the N and f in every iteration and play around. You will realize.